# Verification of proof of convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-1)^n \dfrac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, ratio

Could someone please verify my solution to the following question?

Question: Does $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-1)^n \dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ converge?

Answer: I have verified with WolframAlpha that it does converge. I wish to know if my proof is correct:

Define $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n n!}{n^n}$. Then $$\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \dfrac{(n+1)!n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1} n!} = (1+1/n)^{-n}.$$

Hence, we see that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \dfrac{1}{e}<1$ from which we deduce that the series is absolutely convergent by the ratio test. Hence the series in question converges.

Comment: Seems Ok to me.

Comment: One could also use the Alternating Series Test. But your method gives the stronger conclusion that it converges absolutely.

Comment: This is fine and then (+1). You also could have use that, by Stirling approximation, $\frac{n!}{n^n} \sim  \sqrt{2 \pi n } \, e^{-n}$

Comment: Without using any strong results, the term added is (1/n)(2/n)(3/n)...(n/n), and the first n/2 of these terms are less than 1/2 with the rest at most 1, making the term added less than 2^-(n/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine. You may also notice that for any $n\geq 1$
$$ \frac{n!}{n^n} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} n z^n e^{-nz}\,dz $$
so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{n!}{n^n} x^n = 1-x\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z e^z}{(e^z+xz)^2}\,dz$$
where the radius of convergence of the LHS is given by the supremum of $\rho\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $e^z > \rho z$ for any $z>0$, i.e. by $e$ as also shown by Stirling's approximation.